# How to show rational function field of an affine subvariety with dim>0 is not algebraically closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I do not know how to show the following statement.

> If $X\subset A^n$ is an irreducible subvariety, $\dim X>0$,
>   then the rational function field of $X$, $K(X)$ is not algebraic closed.

What I feel is like following:
If $K(X)$ is alg closed, then I pick up some none constant rational function f on X, f $\in K(X)$, so it has n$^{th}$ root $g_n$for all n, and $g_n$ is also a rational function. so $f^n$=$g_n$ and after reduction of fractions, each gives an equation holds on X and for n to be different prime p, since A(X) is finitely generated. This seems like a contradiction.

But the above does not look like a proof. 
Can anyone give a clean and neat proof of it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably overkill, but noether normalization is one approach.

Comment: @Slade, I agree. It seems no way to be algebraic closed. But I do not know how to construction an equation without solution nor a nontrivial algebraic extension of it. That should be a much nicer proof.

Comment: Just a note, since I'm not sure how updates are triggered: my proof was incomplete in dimension $>1$, and I've updated with corrections and some technical details.

Comment: Dear @Jyrki, your comment is absolutely correct and elegant so that I encourage you to transform it into an answer.

Comment: @Slade, thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take some $f\in k[X]$ that is neither zero nor a unit.  We will show that we cannot take arbitrary roots of $f$ in $k(X)$.

Here is a sketch of the proof for curves:

Because $f$ is not a unit, there is some (regular) $p\in X$ with $f(p) = 0$.  Because $f$ is not zero, it has some finite order of vanishing $n$ at $p$.  But then $f$ cannot be an $(n+1)$-th power of a rational function, i.e. $T^{n+1}-f$ has no root in $k(X)$.

---

The above is a decent intuitive argument, but I think it's problematic to talk about the order of vanishing at an arbitrary point when $X$ has dimension $>1$.  We should pick the (scheme-theoretic) generic point of a codimension $1$ subvariety.

Here is a more detailed version, that works in all dimensions:

---

First, we may assume $X$ is smooth—otherwise, restrict to an affine open away from the singular locus, which does not change the function field.

By Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem, $f$ is contained in a height $1$ prime $P \subset k[X]$.  The localization $k[X]_P$ is a regular local ring of dimension $1$, so it is a DVR.

Suppose there exists some $g\in K(X)$ with $g^k = f$.  Taking valuations, we see that $k\nu_P (g) = \nu_P (f)$ is a multiple of $k$.

Since $\nu_P (f)>0$, this is only possible for finitely many $k$, so there are infinitely many $k$ for which $T^k - f$ has no solution in $K(X)$ (for example, $k=n+1$).

Comment: Thanks. This is very clear!

Comment: Dear Slade, could you please explain what the order of vanishing of $f$ at $p$ means and how you deduce your last sentence ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you for bringing this up.  The proof makes sense in dimension 1, and I think I was intending to reduce to this case, but indeed, there are complications regarding "order of vanishing" in higher dimension.  I've added some technical comments regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

A different route (independent of the dimension) is to start by recalling [Emmy Noether's normalization lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma). It implies that the function field $K(X)$ is a finitely generated algebraic extension of the field of rational functions $L=K(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_d)$ for some algebraically independent elements $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_d, d\le n$ that form a transcendence basis of $K(X)/K$. Here $d=\dim X$, but that isn't actually needed in what follows.

A finitely generated algebraic extension is always finite, so we can conclude that $[K(X):L]=N$ for some positive integer $N(<\infty)$. On the other hand the field $L$ has algebraic extensions of degrees $>N$. For example $L'=L(y_1^{1/(N+1)})$ is an extension field of degree $[L':L]=N+1$. If the field $K(X)$ were algebraically closed, it should contain the field $L'$, but we just saw that this cannot be the case.

Therefore $K(X)$ cannot be algebraically closed.

Comment: I love your proof. Thanks!